# Destroy session in Pylons or Python

Tags: python, session, pylons

I can't find information on how to destroy / kill a session within Pylons or Python on the interwebs.  Thought it would be a good idea just to ask it here so that when I need to do it again a year from now I'll find this question :)

So I'm looking for a PHP session_destroy() equivalent for Pylons or Python.

Thanks,
Maggi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`session.delete()` or `session.invalidate()`, depending on what you want.

http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions.html#deleting